# Pandas python help - can't seem to get the code to do what I need it to

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm, pandas-datareader

[image]I have to write a script to read a csv file and drop columns with a '.' and read strings False and True as 0 and 1. I have been able to code the drop columns fine but I'm having trouble with having pandas read False as a 0 and True as a 1 so that the entire data can be seen in numbers. All other data is float so I believe I must iterate to find False and True and get it to be read as 0 and 1. Below is the code I have so far and I have attached a sample data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

def ImportCustomScript(filename):

    data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', header=None)
    cols = data.shape[1]
    data_list=[]
    
    for i in range(cols):
        if i=='.' in data.columns:
           data.drop([i], axis=1)

    data_list.append([data[i][0], np.array(data[cols][1:], dtype='<f8')])
    data.replace('False',0).replace('True',1)

    data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
    return data_frame
```

Comment: Hi NewbieCoder, welcome to SO. It is good practice to make questions reproducible, so if you could include the actual file, or even better, produce a very small dataframe which reproduces the problem you are having, would increase your chances of receiving helpful answers.

Comment: @zabop the original csv file has 30k rows and 334 columns. Wasn't sure how to add that file on here. The first row is labels and everything else below is floats with some data say False and some that say True instead of floats. If you have any suggestions on how to add the file or maybe an image of part of it I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi NewbieCoder!  So can you give an example of 1 or 2 lines of data your dataframe is reading in?

Because I'm not sure what you mean by reading in a string 'False'/'True'.  Is the string just containing either of those words?  Or does it have other words/characters involved?

Comment: Instead of Pandas reading the csv file in with the True and False words within the data it would read it as 0 and 1's. Did I clarify better?

Answer (score 0):

could perhaps do this, though more info on your actual data would be useful

```
print(df)

     col   col2   col3.
0   True      5       6
1  False      6       3
2   True     32       5
3  False      3       9

df = df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('\.')]]
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int) #or df.loc[:,'col'] = df['col'].astype(int)
```

Comment: The actual csv file contains more than 30k rows and 334 columns. So I cannot use specific column labels

Comment: Then use replace for the second part

Comment: Or make a mask of bool  columns to make ints

Comment: I first used          data = data.replace('False',0).replace('True',1)       but that did not work either. I think it might be that I have the wrong syntax for Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve both tasks is to mask the columns according to the properties you want.

For the first part, assuming `data` is your DataFrame, you can mask out (using `~`) the columns containing a dot:

```
data = data[~data.columns.str.contains("\.")]
```

For the second part, as `pd.read_csv` already recognizes boolean columns, you can convert only the boolean columns to `int` using `pd.DataFrame.astype`:

```
data = data.astype({col: int for col in data.columns[data.dtypes == bool]})
```

EDIT

If for some reason the `pd.read_csv` does not automatically convert the `"True"` and `"False"` strings into booleans, you can use the following solution to first recognize the columns containing only these strings and then replace them with your integer codes:

```
for col in data.columns[data.dtypes == object]:
    if data[col].str.match("^True|False$").all():
        data[col].replace({"True": 1, "False": 0}, inplace=True)
```

EDIT 2

According to the image that you attached recently, the strings `"True"` and `"False"` are mixed with other values. My previous answer, instead, refers to the situation where all values of a column are formed by these strings.

Therefore, to achieve the result you want you can replace all values as follows:

```
def ImportCustomScript(filename):
    # read the csv
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')

    # remove the columns whose name contains a dot
    df = df[~df.columns.str.contains("\.")]

    # replace all "True"/"False" strings
    df.replace({"True": 1, "False": 0}, inplace=True)

    # if you want to convert everything to float
    df = df.astype(float)

    return df
```

Comment: @NewbieCoder, I updated the answer according to the image that you attached. Does it solve your problem?